# To open a bootstrap modal window, if a condition is true in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
if ($sql1 == true) {
    echo '<script> $("#myModal1").show();</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script> $("#myModal1").show();</script>';
}
```

I am trying to open a modal window when a data is inserted in database using php. I have checked the insert condition using if statement to display the modal window. But it is not working.

Comment: Are you using AJAX or not? If not, you can try this. Make your modal like this

`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" style="<?php echo $sql1 ? 'display:block; opacity:1;' : ''; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if($sql1==true)
{
    echo '<script> $("#myModal1").modal("show");</script>';
}
else
{
   echo '<script> $("#myModal2").modal("show");</script>';
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but there is a error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Check if it will work with jQuery(...).modal. your jQuery may be in compatability mode, also check if jQuery is not included twice.

Comment: there is a big probability that bootstrap.js is not loaded before you try to call .modal()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use modal("show") instead of show() :

```
if ($sql1 == true) {
   echo '<script> $("#myModal1").modal("show");</script>';
} else {
   echo '<script> $("#myModal1").modal("show");</script>';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: What is the use of conditional statement if their results is the same? same `<script> $("#myModal1").modal("show");</script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo'<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
if($sql1==true)
    echo '<script> $("#myModal1").modal(\'show\');</script>';
else
   echo '<script> $("#myModal1").modal(\'show\');</script>';
```

Comment: It will show an error. Check your `'` in show. it should be something `"`. And also, in this code, it means that either the `$sql1` is `true` or `false` it will show the modal. Check the logic.